# move object in a projectile path

Tags: java, android, physics

I'm working on an android project, I want to move an object in a projectile path, but have no idea how to do that..

I got the initial X and initial Y, i.e. left bottom corner of the phone in landscape mode. Also I fetch the X and Y were the user touch the phone, so I can calculate the angle too by tan-1(y/x), but how to calculate the curve path  i.e X and Y for the object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @singhh : well that is a pure mathematical problem , are you facing problem in doing the maths or some programming problem ???

Comment: Yes , I skipped projectile motion chapter in my school classes, and now its haunting me, can you please explain how to find the X and Y at every point of a projectile path ?

Comment: can cocos2d-x help me on this ?
as I'm using it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You have initial point p1 (X, Y) where you throw your projectile. And you have a point where user touched the screen, say p2. So, find the direction vector, like dir = p2 - p1 and normalize it. Then do following:

1. You have initial velocity, v = speed * dir, where speed is scalar factor
2. Then, on every game tick append to your current position vector `v = v + (0, -10); v *= dt`, where (0, -10) is gravity factor and dt - time between game frames.

Comment: flamingo : thank you for your help, but can you please explain it with some mathematical exmaple, like initialX=0m, initialY=0m, initialV=50m/s and angle is 45 degree or 1 radian..

Comment: using these initial values, how to get x1 and y1 ?? of the next game tick?

Comment: knowing this, I could calculate the x2 and y2 and so on for the projectile motion :)

Comment: Okay. P1 = (0, 0). If angle = 45 degrees, so directional vector is (1, 1). Normalize it: dir(0.707, 0.707). Initial velocity is v = 50 * (0.707, 0,707) = (35, 35)
For example, dt = 0.1
First tick: projectile_point = (0, 0) + dt * (35, 35) = (3.5, 3.5)
Second: v = (35, 35) + (0, -10) = (35, 25); v = 0.1 * (35, 25) = (3.5, 2.5)
s = (3.5, 3.5) + (3.5, 2.5) = (7, 6)

etc

Comment: So, your x1 = 3.5, y1 = 2.5; x2 = 7, y2 = 6 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate having to increment by time intervals by using the parametric form of the projectile equations.

All you'd need to do is determine how far across (left to right) the screen you want to travel. I'll call that the X direction. Then, for each position in the X direction (could be a pixel, could be some number of pixels), you calculate the corresponding position in the Y (down to up) direction.

You'll need to set a value for the downward acceleration due to gravity. Whatever value you choose, I'll just call it g. You'll also need to set a value for how fast the projectile begins it's motion. Whatever value you choose, I'll just call it V.

The parametric equation is then:

Y = X * tan(theta) - (g * X^2) / (2 * V^2 * (cosine(theta))^2)

So, once you have the user touch point, you can calculate the angle, theta, determine V, g, and the maximum value for X, then just iterate from 0 to max X and you'll get a point (X,Y) for each iteration.